# Sending Dynamic Data with Sendrid SMTP

Tags: laravel, email, sendgrid

I have created a Dynamic Template on SendGrid. Inside the template I am using Handlebars to render my dynamic data.

My back end is built with Laravel.  Now rather than designing blade views I'm relying on SendGrid's dynamic templating with handlebars.

Now my problem is I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere on how to send this dynamic data along with my mail to SendGrid using the SMTP api.  The only option I see now is using SendGrid's Web Api.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can not templates with SMTP. You can use it only using SendGrid Web API.

Check out this library: https://github.com/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver. It supports templates.